# html email image on a 2 rows shows blank space in the middle on browser

Tags: html, email, html-email

I made an HTML email in Dreamweaver.

I have used a table to contain the body of the email.

I have added images, in rows. However in the browser the images leave a blank space in the middle. This only happens when I look at the email on Hotmail. Microsoft Outlook is fine. I don't understand why this is happening

![as you can see on the html email(hotmail) it shows like this, but in outlook there is no space!!!][1]

as you can see on the html email(hotmail) it shows like this, but in outlook there is no space!

html code:

```
          <td height="8" valign="top" colspan="2"><img src="images/greenTop01.gif" alt="top" width="595" height="8" valign="top" display:"block" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="453" height="115" valign="top" bgcolor="#18b581"><p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF; display:block; margin-left: 25px;"><strong><font size="4">Could you have a patient with NP-C?</font>
```

ful html: http://jsfiddle.net/eNKxp/1/

Comment: `margin: "100px"` is invalid, also, you should set the height on the `td`, so `<td height="100">`, and also use `valign` to vertically align everything to the top. `<td valign="top">`

Comment: @al123 Can you put this code into jsFiddle please.

Comment: For best user experience, just make a screenshot of your email in dreamweaver, cut it down to the email only, and send that image only. This way you can circumvent any possible client compatibility issues.

Comment: @Alexander It will be even more likely to be marked as spam, as the filter won't be able to read any text...

Comment: full html : http://jsfiddle.net/eNKxp/1/

Comment: @NickR have you had a look at the full html, i dont understand why in some browser it shows and others it doesnt

Comment: @al123 http://jsfiddle.net/eNKxp/2/ - I've updated your Fiddle, and added `style="display:block"` to all images, I did a quick find and replace, so might not be perfect.

Comment: yeh, copied it to new html page, it still showing the white space on hotmail...

Comment: possible duplicate of [outlook not aligning 2 images but other browsers are](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21025156/outlook-not-aligning-2-images-but-other-browsers-are)

Comment: Isn't this pretty much the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21025156/outlook-not-aligning-2-images-but-other-browsers-are ? You shouldn't repost questions, instead update your question if the scope changes as you work through the issue.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `display:block` for the images. See this table to have an idea about html support for email templates: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: @al123 `display:block` should be added to the style attribute ;-)

Comment: `display:"block"` is not valid. Use `style="display:block"`. Also it's a good idea to use old `align` rule for the cells. Before using this sintax make sure you have a valid html4 doctype(as in html5 `align` rule for example is deprecated)

Comment: Can you post the full `HTML` document.

Comment: `display: "block">`, you don't need `"` - remove the double quotes from block